# Convert List<T> to List<string>

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list, converters

I have a class and list:

```
public class sorting
{
    public string conLineOne { get; set; }
    public string conLineTwo { get; set; }
}

public static List<sorting> preSorted = new List<sorting>();
```

and in a method I have

```
List<string> parametersList = new List<string>();
```

and I want to create parametersList with each element conLineOne and conLineTwo.

For example:

preSorted:

```
conLineOne: apple conLineTwo: banana 
conLineOne: pear  conLineTwo: strawberry
```

Then I want parametersList:

```
apple

banana

pear 

strawberry
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SelectMany()` to project each source entity to multiple destination entities:

```
List<string> foo = input.SelectMany(f => new[] 
    { 
         f.conLineOne, 
         f.conLineTwo 
    })
    .ToList();
```

This will list the `conLineOne` followed by the `conLineTwo` of each `input` element.

Comment: +1 I didn't know that we can use `SelectMany` this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Select.

```
List<string> parametersList = preSorted
    .OrderBy(x => x.conLineOne)
    .ThenBy(x => x.conLineTwo)
    .Select(x => x.conLineTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to do without Linq too:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in preSorted)
{
    result.Add(item.conLineOne);
    result.Add(item.conLineTwo);
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Pls try following,

var stringList = myList.OfType();

Comment: Maybe you should try the code in your answers yourself before suggesting the questioner to do so.

Comment: This does not come anywhere near what the OP has asked for. He wants to create a new list of strings, containing the values of his sorted collection.